# How to update a resource view count in REST API?

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

I have an application containing videos. Each of the videos has a view count (represented by a property `total_views`) along with other properties such as its title, uploader, etc. A video view count should be incremented by 1 every time a video is requested/watched. The frontend of this application is a Next.js SPA and the backend is a Lumen/Laravel REST API.

The current REST API backend solution returns the `total_views` as part of the video entity when the `GET /videos/{id}` endpoint is called on the API.

I am not sure how to implement video count updates in the most REST generally accepted convention compliant way.
I thought of updating the count on a request to `GET /videos/{id}` but I believe that this is not common REST standards/specification compliant (causing issues with caching, etc.) since the `total_views` property of the entity object in the response is being updated too.
The second option I thought of is using another endpoint such as `POST/PUT/PATCH /videos/{id}/views`. However, I do not want to use a request body as the backend API should always increment by 1 only (and this way avoiding the client tampering with the view count). Another drawback of this option is that it introduces extra overhead as it requires sending another HTTP request in addition to the GET request for getting the video info.

What are your suggestions?

**EDIT:** Video view count here might also be seen as page view counts instead of actual video views/plays (*Video resource* views). Accurate view counting that filters out page views of crawlers, bots, or views where the visitor did not start the video are outside the scope of this question.

The videos are hosted by external 3-rd party hosts and are only embedded via embed codes (iframe) in this application's video web pages.

Comment: There is no accurate nor reliable way to count video views - YouTube does it better than most sites/services are able to because they control the client software, but if your clients are all web-browsers then the best you can do is a rough approximation. Anyway, there's nothing wrong with counting `GET` requests for video files (and I think you're thinking too rigidly about `GET`'s "no mutation"  semantics). Also, I want to stress that **"REST" isn't a standard nor a specification** so "REST-compliance" is a meaningless term, it's just an _architectural style_.

Comment: @Dai I agree with your answer. The main reasons that stopped me using GET for updating the view count were the caching concern since although an example response for a web browser calling the endpoint might be `{"title": "video a", total_count": 20}` the same even after calling it twice (because of "count 1 view only for 24 hours" constraint), it is going to be different after another visitor's web browser calls it (e.g. `{"title": "video a", total_count": 21}`).

Indeed, I was sloppy with saying "REST-compliant", I meant compliment with the common popular specifications/guidelines for REST.

Comment: The `GET` request _for a video's metadata in JSON_ (which is what you're describing) probably should not increment the view-count, correct - you should instead be logging/counting requests for the actual binary video files (how are you serving those? you haven't said, but that's a very important detail)

Comment: The API response is indeed in JSON. The videos are hosted externally by 3-rd parties and included in the SPA web app via embed codes. However, I need to store the view count in an SQL RDBMS to use it throughout the web app. I don't want to rely on the APIs of the external video hosts for counting views. At this point, I am not very concerned with bots/crawlers traffic that might skew the view count statistics.

Comment: If you're using a dedicated third-party video hosting service then they'll have their own guidance for the best way to get viewcounts. I suggest you contact them first.

Comment: @Dai I am not using a dedicated hosting service. The embed codes can be from a variety of video hosts and I do not trust the counters implemented in some of them.

Comment: Then what you're asking is impossible, because those "embed codes" **control the client**.

Comment: @Dai What would be the consequences if I proceed to implement the video view count update (as an exception) as a procedure executed during the video data fetch request `GET /videos/{id}`? Then that endpoint will also update the view count and return the updated video in JSON in a format similar to `"id":1, "title": "Example video", "uploader_id": 3, description: "Example description", total_views: 20}`.

Comment: I can't tell you because I don't know what causes `GET /videos/{id}` to be requested or what caching headers you're setting on the response (that said, "live" data should always have `Cache-Control: no-store` applied).

Comment: @Dai What do you mean with the embed codes controlling the client? Could you elaborate a bit more? The client in my case is my website which I have control over. I don't use any of the embed code information for view counting. I want to have my own view counting solution so that view counting does not depend on the numerous 3-rd party embed players embedded in the website via embed codes.

Comment: The "client" isn't a website, it's the end-user's web-browser; and if it's part of a website you "have no control over" and you don't even host the video files or streams yourself then there's _nothing_ you can do. That's just how the web works.

Comment: @Dai By video counting, I meant possibly counting the page views on my site (as an alternative). There is no need to have the real video play count. I should have been more explicit with this as it was ambiguous to call it *video view count*.

Comment: Page views don't need any client-side scripts or logic, just use your own HTTP server logs or appropriate middleware/module/filter for whatever server-side framework you're using.

Comment: @Dai Replying to your previous replies, I can set `Cache-Control: no-store` to make sure the GET request gets executed always (and view count updates along with this).

`GET /videos/{id}` is called whenever a video page is loaded.

Comment: @Dai I meant handling the view counts in the backend (using Laravel). I am not planning to use client scripts for that. My idea was: 1. A user clicks on a video link in the website. 2. The browser sends an HTTP request to the backend `GET /videos/{id}`. 3. The backend updates the view count and returns a response in JSON, containing all data of a "video" *Resource* including the updated view count.

Comment: But you said you don't have any way of scripting the web-browser to make that `GET / videos/{id}` request because you don't control the website it's shown in.

Comment: If you _can_ count the view when the actual `GET` request happens, I would also recommend that. Having a separate endpoint just means someone *could* abuse it and call it many times... but preventing that is a bit out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @Dai kataba said verbatim: "The client in my case is my website which I have control over"

Comment: Aaaaah, I incorrectly misread them as saying "have _no_ control over" (the phrase "which I have no control over" in English is used far more commonly than "which I have control over" - usually it's written as "which I have full control over" which asserts the positive - serves me right for speed-reading...)

Comment: @Dai No, I never meant that. I have full access over the frontend application (since it is implemented by me and hosted by me).

Comment: @kataba Please disregard everything I wrote after that point then :)

Comment: @Evert, thank you for the remark. Indeed, I agree that the safest way is to handle the view count update while handling the GET request. If I were to use a standalone endpoint for updating the count (e.g. `PATCH /videos/{id}/views` with a filter for 1 view per video per IP per day), my concern was that I would have to send a PATCH request with an empty body (as I don't want someone changing the view count tampering).

Comment: @kataba have you seen my answer? I addressed that and more ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want correctly, you really want an 'increment' operation. This operation does not need a previous count, send the new total.

The best fitting HTTP method is indeed `PATCH`. `PATCH` can do many things, and it's up to you to decide the meaning. For example, if your `PATCH` request looks like this, it's 100% correct:

```
PATCH /videos/{id}/views
Content-Type: application/vnd.your-company-name.increment
Content-Length: 0
```

You can also invent a little JSON format:

```
PATCH /videos/{id}/views
Content-Type: application/vnd.your-company-name.increment+json

{
  "action": "increment"
}
```

The first format does not use a body at all, which is what you asked for.. but since your goal with the empty body was to prevent tampering with the number, it's not actually required to use an empty body.

It might be less confusing to users that only ever use JSON with APIs that you have an endpoint without a body, so the second example is a very little JSON document that just tell the server to increment the view count.

You don't strictly *have* to use a custom mimetype. Its a good idea, but if you don't want to you use can also use `application/octet-stream` and `application/json` for these two requests respectively.

### A better plan

I do believe its actually better the GET request to the video itself, instead of having the tracking done as a side-effect via javascript.

Given that you mention that you're on PHP, you could for example do this using the XSendFile module (if you're on nginx, other servers probably have an equivalent):

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/

The general steps are:

1. Intercept the GET request to the actual video with PHP
2. Count the view
3. Using XSendFile, send the file over (so you don't keep an active PHP process for the duration of sending the video).

If the file is hosted entirely something else, like S3, there might also be ways to tap into the server access log and count GET requests there.

Comment: I updated my question. I should have been more specific. _The videos are hosted by external 3-rd party hosts and are only embedded via their embed codes (iframe) in this application's video web pages._ I have no control over the actual video files.

**Edit: Counting page views instead of real video plays is also fine with me.**

Comment: Also, the REST API is planned to be used only internally - only for the sake of the application's functionality (with the SPA implemented by me).

Comment: Do you think that updating the (page) view count in the database at the time of processing the `GET /videos/{id}` request is fine as an alternative solution (although mutating the same video resource that is being returned by the endpoint) as long as `Cache-Control: no-store` is used?

Comment: Yeah that's also fine as long as tracking that is fine to _you_! This is a 'product' question more than a programming question i think =)